# At least one member of S is a divisor of another member of S

Tags: algebra-precalculus

S is a set of 20 positive integers, all of which have a units digit of 2 and are less than 1000.

Now

> "**At least one member of S is a divisor of another member of S**."

Is it true for this case?

What I think is that, the integer can be anything involving unit digit 2 and less than 1000. Let's guess some numbers: 002, 012, 022 ,852, 862 etc. If we multiply any of the integer with the another one, then  we never get a integer with unit digit 2.  **Therefore the statement can not be true. Am I right?**

Answer (score 1):

By the reason you give, it's true that the *product of two elements in $ S $* isn't in $ S $. But one of the elements of $ S $ could still divide another. For example, in the set you give, $ 2 $ is a divisor of $ 12 $ because $ 6 \times 2 = 12 $. In fact, $ 2 $ divides all of the other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set
$$S := \{992,982,972,\ldots,852\},$$
Then for any $s_i \in S$ we have $s_i \geq 501$ and thus for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k \geq 2$ we have

$$s_i \cdot k \geq s_i \cdot 2 > 1000 \implies s_i\cdot k \notin S,$$ it follows that  $s_i$ can't be a divisor of an element in $S$ (except of himself).